# What is a "rehab stint"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have looked through all dictionary meanings of "stint" (even at the Urban Dictionary), but have not found a meaning which is implied in "rehab stint" as a collocation. I have found a longer collocation, "drag rehabilitation stint", and I suppose "stint" means something similar to "stay". But I am not sure, because, since the primary meaning of "stint" is limitation, this also may mean obligatory stay, i.e. imposed on someone by authorities.

I'd like to know the exact meaning of "stint" here.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, snobu. When you get a moment click on this [**Link**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the TOUR, if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this site, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about rep and site privileges. It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, you’re off to a good start. Enjoy the site and we’ll see you around, so to speak. :-)

Comment: Two of the first three dictionaries I checked in had the 'time spent doing something' sense, and it was strongly hinted at in the third.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was also going to close as General, but when I looked in Oxford, the stint as an activity was not there so I answered instead

Comment: @mplungian I think that AHDEL and Collins should be the benchmarks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Stint](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stint): a period of time spent doing something:
  *a two-year stint in the army* <sub>[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)</sub>
- [Rehab](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rehab?s=t): rehabilitation, especially a program or facility for treating persons addicted to drugs or alcohol or recovering from certain medical conditions:
  *He's been sober since coming out of rehab.*
  <sub>[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)</sub>

So [Rehab Stint](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22rehab+stint%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=mdv2VOilDsnJPNvYgJgM) is a (short) period of rehabilitation (from abuse)

This might be where you read it - the text illustrates the words very well:

> **Jon Jones' rehab stint lasted just a day; simply a charade**
>   According to his mother, Jones' stay in a drug treatment center in New Mexico lasted all of one night. And that makes everything that went down last week after news broke that Jones tested positive for benzoylecgonine, the main metabolite in cocaine, seems like nothing more than a publicity stunt and/or an effort at damage control.

[Rehab stint amy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rehab++stint%22+amy)

> - Amy Winehouse performing after her latest rehab stint
> - ...canceled due to the rehab stint
> - Rehab stint: Amy Winehouse's husband ...

Comment: At your service, @LittleEva

Comment: OP, it's also worth noting that 'rehab stint' is quite [tabloid language](http://voiceseducation.org/content/shocking-secrets-revealed-language-tabloid-headlines) - which is to say, it's informal with a definite tone of pejorative sensationalism (in BrEng at least). A more neutral way to way to say it would be that the person is "in recovery" or "in treatment" for a drug or alcohol "problem" or "addiction", e.g. ["Public Health England invests £10m in drug and alcohol recovery services"](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/public-health-england-invests-10m-in-drug-and-alcohol-recovery-services)

Comment: It seems to be widely used in headlines, but not just by tabloids in the US at least: http://edition.cnn.com/2008/SHOWBIZ/Music/02/20/amy.brit/index.html?eref=ew